# Using PageMap or custom Meta tags in Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

I have a search engine on my site that searches using several custom fields. I need to search through the content of PDF files so I am implementing Google Custom Search Engine. However, I still need the ability to use my custom filtering.

I am trying to do it via PageMap or meta tags with custom content, but for some reason it doesn't work. For example, in this page:
http://che.org.il/?decision=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%92-18-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%92

I have put both methods in the header:

```
<meta name="dec_sit" content="18-527" />
<meta name="dec_univ" content="" />
<meta name="dec_date" content="2013-04-30" />
<meta name="dec_category" content="46" />

<!--
<PageMap>
    <Databject type="metatags">
        <Attribute name="category">46</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="dec_date">2013-04-30</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="dec_univ"></Attribute>
    <Attribute name="dec_sit">18-527</Attribute>
</DataObject>
</PageMap>
-->
```

However, when I try to search through the property dec_sit, it doesn't work:
[https://www.google.com/cse?cx=008755111893149603021:c5o41aeaazc&q=אודות+more:pagemap:metatags-dec_sit:18](https://www.google.com/cse?cx=008755111893149603021%3ac5o41aeaazc&q=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20more%3apagemap%3ametatags-dec_sit:18)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change how you are using the attribute tags. Currently your attribute tags are breaking when it trying to parse the xml.

```
<!--
<PageMap>
    <Databject type="metatags">
     <Attribute name="category" value="46" />
    <Attribute name="dec_date" value="2013-04-30" />
    <Attribute name="dec_univ" value="" />
    <Attribute name="dec_sit" value="18-527" />
</DataObject>
</PageMap>
-->
```